# Set variable before segue transition happens

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, swift, segue

I have a UITableView which I have set up to go to a different VC when a row is selected by the user (the table only consists of one array). I want to pass the row index of the selected item. I am using `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to set a variable named `selectedCellIndex` to the row index. However, since I also have the tableView set up to go to the next VC `prepareForSegue` fires off (or around the same time) as `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. As a result the first time I select an item from the list the value sent is nil, after that I always get the previous value of the row selected. Any Ideas on how to make sure that the variable is set before the app transitions to the next segue without putting a pause?

Here is my code:

```
var selectedCellIndex:Int!

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
    var indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() as NSIndexPath?
    selectedCellIndex = indexPath?.row as Int?
}


//SEGUE
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "signature" {
        let vc = segue.destinationViewController as SignatureViewController
        vc.index = "\(selectedCellIndex)"
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the selected index path from the table view directly using the `indexPathForSelectedRow` method. There is no need to implement `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` just to store the selected index.

The `prepareForSegue:` method is the only method where you should set/access variables that are necessary for a transition.